# Keyboard shortcut to move cursor to last edit position in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, editor, keyboard-shortcuts

In Visual Studio, is there a keyboard shortcut to navigate (move cursor) to the last *edited* position (like PyCharm's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd>)?

The <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> shourtcut moves to the last position (not the last *edited* position), which is less useful for me.

Comment: Another existing implementation: Eclipse, which uses Ctrl-Q to jump to the last edited position.

Comment: @yariv Did you find the shortcut?

Answer (score 12):

This shortcut was added in VS2017 version 15.8:

Ctrl + Shift + Backspace

It's near impossible to find via google, I just stumbled across it when reading the VS news and release notes.

> Go To Last Edited Location
>
> We all know the feeling of starting to
> write a feature and then realizing we need some more information from
> elsewhere in the solution. So, we open another file from Solution
> Explorer or Go to Definition in a few places and suddenly, we’re far
> off from where we started with no easy way back unless you remember
> the name of file you were working in originally. In Visual Studio 2017
> version 15.8, you can now go back to your last edited location via
> Edit > Go To > Go To Last Edit Location (Ctrl + Shift + Backspace).

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2018/08/30/improving-your-productivity-in-the-visual-studio-editor/

Answer (score 5):

You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> (View.NavigateBackward) shortcut.

Comment: .. or assign a custom shortcut for `View.NavigateBackward`.

Comment: Again this doesn't do what the OP requested - "to the last *edited* position"

Answer (score 5):

In my VS I can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd>. I am not sure if this Works in all Versions and With different keyboard layout.

Answer (score 4):

You can do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>z</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>y</kbd>.

This does an undo/redo, so your code will not be affected, but your code window will be moved to the last edit location.

I have Visual Studio 2010, and this does the trick for me.

Comment: I use this method also, only it doesn't work on multiple files - only on the last file

Comment: This is the only correct answer given the OP's question - "to the last edited position".  I also use this method, but was hoping to be able to cycle through the list to edited positions.

Comment: It works most of the time for me, but not always, unfortunately. Not sure what it depends on.

Answer (score 4):

I always use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd>.

Comment: Via another answer: this was only added in VS17 (15.8). This was only released in April 2018 and the post is from June 16  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ `Edit.GoToLastEditLocation` is the binding for it if you want to change the shortcut. I changed it to something better accessible (only two keys)

Answer (score 1):

Additionally you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> (View.NavigateForward) shortcut.

Comment: This doesn't do what the OP requested - "to the last *edited* position"

Comment: Thank you, I was seeking this info!

Answer (score 1):

There is a free extension for Visual Studio 2015, 2017, 2019 that includes it : 
[Hot Commands](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JustinClareburtMSFT.HotCommandsforVisualStudio)

```
Edit.GoToLastEditLocation
```

> Takes the caret back to the last place an edit occurred during that
>   session.

The default Keyboard shortcut is : <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Backspace</kbd>

This can be changed any time under Tools - Options - Environment - Keyboard - Edit.GoToLastEditLocation

Edit: Extension now also support VS2019

Answer (score 0):

Many of the answers mention VisualStudio 2017 or a plugin to VisualStudio 2015.

I found the following shortcuts in VisualStudio 2015.

```
View.NavigateBackward
View.ForwardBackward
```

Map nicely to pycharm's

```
Last Edit Location
Next Edit Location
```