# visual studio go to previous edit locations

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I am trying to stop using ReSharper we got too slow for me. One functionality that seems missing is the ability to navigate through the previous edit locations. Is that not available?

There is `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Bkspce` for `Edit.GoToLastEditLocation` but I can't seem to be able to go further.

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20324385/keyboard-shortcut-to-move-cursor-to-last-edit-position-in-visual-studio) the same question?

Comment: not really, I am not looking for this resharper feature: 'View Recent Edits'.